# How to get multiple conditions in case in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to run a query on some fields of the table, but I cant understand how to do it. I have the condition that first I need to check value of **col1**, if it is 'W', then I need to check **colA** having values in ('1','2'), if it is not 'W', then I need to check **colB** having values in ('1','2').
This condition to check ('1','2') applies same to both colA and colB, just depending on the value of col1.

I tried using this, but obviously this is incorrect.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE CASE WHEN col1= 'W' THEN (colA IN ('1','2')) ELSE (colB IN ('1','2')) END
```

So how can I do it in a single query without using Unions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Sql Server-2014 : Use **CASE** to choose column to be used in **WHERE** clause based on condition-

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 
WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN col1= 'W' THEN colA ELSE colB END) in ('1', '2');
```

**Tested on SqlServer-2014**. image attached

MySql : Use **IF() function** to choose column to be used in **WHERE** clause based on condition-

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 
WHERE 
    IF(col1='W', colA, colB) in ('1', '2');
```

Comment: Nakesh, I got empty table from query. Will you please updated your answer with example....._/\\_

Comment: Image attached in my answer. Tested on SqlServer-2014 version

Comment: @Nakesh Thanks, this looks cleaner and simpler approach.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `CASE`, just put all your boolean logic together in one expression.

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE
    (Col1 = 'W' AND ColA IN ('1', '2'))
    OR
    (Col1 <> 'W' AND ColB IN ('1', '2'))
;
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted. Cheers!